# How to use a property, in a django template, from a mongoengine model

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine with Django.  I have a class, Noun, from which several other classes (Person, Place, Event, etc.) inherit.  The Noun class looks like this:

```
class Noun(Document):
  label = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
  contributor = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
  description = StringField(required=False)
  @property
  def noun_cls():
      return self._cls
  meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
```

When I try to reference the noun_cls property in the template, I get nothing.  For example:

```
{% for noun in Nouns %}
  <li>
        <a href="{{BASE_URL}}noun/update/{{ noun.id }}/{{ noun.noun_cls }}/">Edit {{ noun.noun_cls }}</a>
    <p>{{ noun.description }}</p>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

...this results in a url like "...noun/update/[long mongo id]//".  It is as if the noun_cls property is being totally ignored.  This is true both with previously existing nouns (or whatever type), and with new ones made after this code change.  Any ideas?

Comment: Properties should just work - is it just that there is no `_cls` value.

Answer (score 0):

change `def noun_cls()` to `def noun_cls(self)` would work!

If you are using Django template engine, it will ignore "non-exist" properties.

In your case, your `def noun_cls()` is missing `self`, django gives nothing instead of raising an exception.